# Extract links in excel cell which contain html tags too

Tags: excel, hyperlink, extract

In my excel sheet i have a column containing some html tags .

Below is the data of 1 cell

```
<div>
  <div> COLOR </div>
  <div>
    <div><img src="**http://resources.*****.com/pim/91/e7/91e7c2f7f400b4724cdf3a3e020272c2.jpg**"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div><img src="**http://resources.*****.com/pim/59/81/598142a72a1951c06068c4b273aba26a.jpg"**></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try to use Asap utility to remove html tags but it also removed required http links.
I need both links in excel cell.Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do data--> text to columns to separate all of the html tags.

please see a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfUtD.jpg

then you can use the search function to strip out the src=""